# HTML attributes having 1:1 relationships with DOM Properties

Tags: html, dom

Which HTML attributes are having 1:1 relationships with DOM Properties?

Comment: Almost all of them. Providing a comprehensive list is too broad of a topic for SO.

Comment: Is there any document reference providing list of all of them?

Comment: It might help if you explain what you want the list for. There's a fair number of cases where the relationship is not quite 1:1, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: I was reading Angular Docs, and I found that `colspan` attribute has no 1:1 relationship. So, it gets little confusing and hard to remember at the time of implementation. So, I am looking for a brief cheat-sheet.